# smallest, largest, and average value of n numbers input by the user

Tags: python

I need to create a function that will print the smallest, largest,and average of `n` amount of numbers inputed by user.

My function, so far, can print the average and largest value of `n` amount of numbers entered by user but I'm stuck on finding the smallest value.

This is what I have so far:

```
def main():

    n = int(input("how many?"))
    if (n>0):
        counter=0
        total=0
        l_v=0

        while counter<n:
            x = int(input("enter next number"))
            total=total+x
            counter=counter+1
            if x>l_v:
                l_v=x


        print ("the largest value is {0}".format(l_v))    
        print("the average is ", total/n)
    else:
        print("What? it is not possible to find the average, sorry ")


main()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As [@Padraic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29721760/smallest-largest-and-average-value-of-n-numbers-input-by-the-user/29721866#comment47578486_29721932) mentioned, [the answer that your posted to your question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29721932/4669462) doesn't work for positive values, since your if-statement only checks if the min value is less that 0.

To fix this, you could just assign the *first inputted value* to all the variables. This way you wouldn't have to use positive and negative `inf` variables:

```
def main():

    n = int(input("how many?")) 
    if (n>0):
        counter=0
        total=0
        f_v = l_v = s_v = total =int (input("enter first value"))  #first value
        while counter<(n-1):
            x = int(input("enter next number"))
            total=total+x
            counter=counter+1
            if x<s_v:    #find minimum
                s_v=x
            elif x>l_v:  #find maximum
                l_v=x

        print ("the smallest value is {0}".format(s_v))        
        print ("the largest value is {0}".format(l_v))    
        print("the average is ", total/n)
    else:
        print("What? it is not possible to find the average, sorry ")


main()
```

Now your code will run without any issues:

```
how many?5
enter first value-1
enter next number7
enter next number0
enter next number3
enter next number2
the smallest value is -1
the largest value is 7
('the average is ', 2.2)
```

Answer (score 2):

Keep track of the lowest number  also, set the start value to `float(inf)` for the min and `float(-inf)`  for the max:

```
if n > 0:
    l_v =  float("-inf") 
    mn_v = float("inf")
    sm, counter = 0, 0     
    while counter < n:
        x = int(input("enter next number"))
        if x < mn:
            mn = x
        if x > l_v:
            l_v = x
        sm += x
        counter += 1
    print("the largest value is {0}".format(l_v))
    print("the average is ", sm / n)
    print("the min value is {}".format(mn_v))
```

You can also use a for loop with range:

```
n = int(input("how many?"))
if n > 0:
    l_v =  float("-inf")
    mn_v = float("inf")
    sm = 0
    for i in range(n):
        x = int(input("enter next number"))
        if x < mn:
            mn = x
        if x > l_v:
            l_v = x
        sm += x
    print("the largest value is {0}".format(l_v))
    print("the average is ", sm / n)
    print("the min value is {}".format(mn_v))
```

Or using a list comp:

```
n = int(input("how many?"))
if n > 0:
    nums = [int(input("enter next number")) for _ in range(n)]
    print ("the largest value is {0}".format(min(nums)))
    print("the average is ", sum(nums)/ n)
    print("the min value is {}".format(min(nums)))
else:
    print("What? it is not possible to find the average, sorry ")
```

`sm += x` is [augmented assignment](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Augmented_assignment) which the  same as doing `sm = sm + x`.

When verifying user input and casting you should really use a `try/except` to catch any [exceptions](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/errors.html#exceptions):

```
def get_num():        
    while True:
        try:
            n = int(input("enter next number"))
            # user entered valid input, return  n
            return n
        except ValueError:
            # could not be cast to int, ask again
            print("Not an interger")

while True:
    try:
        n = int(input("how many?"))
        break
    except ValueError:
        print("Not an interger")

if n > 0:
    l_v =  float("-inf") 
    mn_v = float("inf")
    sm, counter = 0, 0     
    while counter < n:
        x = int(input("enter next number"))
        if x < mn:
            mn = x
        if x > l_v:
            l_v = x
        sm += x
        counter += 1
    print("the largest value is {0}".format(l_v))
    print("the average is ", sm / n)
    print("the min value is {}".format(mn_v))
```

Comment: sorry i should have said that it needs to be a while loop. Maybe i should put f_v = int (input("enter first value") then .... if x<f_v: x=s_v (smallest value)

Comment: @stacker, the logic is still exactly the same whether you use a while loop or range

Answer (score 2):

You could add the items to a list while the user inputs data.

When the user is done, just use `min()`, `max()`, and `sum()` (and maybe `len()`) on the list.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I ended up doing... Just kind of worked it out myself through trial and error.

I really appreciate the answers! Gives me a different way of looking at the problem!

Answer:

```
def main():

    n = int(input("how many?"))
    if (n>0):
        counter=0
        total=1
        l_v=0
        s_v= 0
        f_v = int (input("enter first value"))
        while counter<n:
            x = int(input("enter next number"))
            total=total+x
            counter=counter+1
            if x<f_v:
                s_v=x
            elif x>l_v:
                l_v=x

        print ("the smallest value is {0}".format(s_v))        
        print ("the largest value is {0}".format(l_v))    
        print("the average is ", total/n)
    else:
        print("What? it is not possible to find the average, sorry ")


main()
```

Comment: Your code won't work, unless the user enters a negative number then 0 is always going to be less than any number entered. You would also get caught if the user just entered negative numbers for the highest value or entered the highest value first

Comment: To prevent what @PadraicCunningham pointed out, you may initialize `l_v` to `sys.minint` and `s_v` to `sys.maxint`